# Finding the cdf and the pdf of $Z=X/Y$ given the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-x}e^{-y},  & 0<x<\infty, 0<y<\infty \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I started by trying to find the cdf of Z, having

$$F_z(a)=P(z<a)=P\left(\frac{x}{y}<a\right)=\iint_{\frac{x}{y}<a}(f(x,y))dxdy$$

Not sure how to compute this

Comment: "Not sure how to compute this" Well... $$\iint_{x/y<a}f(x,y)dxdy=\int_0^\infty\int_{x/a}^\infty e^{-x-y}dy\,dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\int_{x/a}^\infty e^{-y}dy\,dx=\ldots$$

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. Sorry my multivariable calc is a bit shaky. can you explain how the region turns into that interval?

Comment: Well, $[x>0,y>0,x/y<a]$ is equivalent to $[x>0,x/a<y]$, qed.